# How would I generate a random sample in python with numbers between 1-x?

Tags: python, random

I am making a class group calculator and have been trying to generate a `random.sample(range(1,16), classNumber)` but when I run the code it seems to still include the number 0 in the sample.

This is my code:

```
import random

classNumber = int(input('Please enter the number of people in your class:'))
groupNumber = int(input('Please enter the number of groups:'))

sum1 = classNumber // groupNumber

if (sum1 * groupNumber) == classNumber:
    for i in range(1,sum1+1):
        print (groupNumber)
    random.seed(1)
    sample = random.sample(range(classNumber+1), classNumber+1)
    print (sample)
    count = 0
    for i in range(1,classNumber+1):
        count += 1
        print(i,'- ',sample[count])
else:
    numbersInGroup = classNumber - (groupNumber * sum1)
    for i in range(1,sum1+1):
        print(groupNumber)
    print(numbersInGroup)
```

Even this is returning errors.

```
import random
s = random.sample(range(1,16),16)
print (s)
```

Comment: Why have you posted the code on pastebin instead of here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy module:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.randint(1,16,6)
```

Here, about inclusive and exclusive random arrays:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html

Answer (score 0):

```
sample = random.sample(range(classNumber+1), classNumber+1)
```

Here's your problem. This sample makes no sense. First, you didn't set a lower bound on the range, so it defaults to 0 instead of 1. Second, if you just increase the lower bound, you'll be trying to draw more numbers from the range than the range actually has. There's no part of your code that says `random.sample(range(1,16), classNumber)`. Is that what this line was supposed to say?

Comment: When I do that I get this error ValueError: Sample larger than population

Comment: @KyleKirkby: Yeah, that's not going to work either. How many numbers do you actually want to draw, and from what range?

Comment: The second argument to random.sample() is the size of the list to return, so you're asking for a sample of, say, 6 people out of 5.

Comment: I want 16 numbers in a range of 1-16

Comment: sample = random.sample(range(1,classNumber), classNumber) this doesn't work either

Comment: even this is returning the 'sample larger than population' error

Comment: `random.sample(range(1, classNumber+1), classNumber)`

Answer (score 0):

The range function needs at least two arguments, the start value (1st value), and the stop value (2nd value). The stop value is not the last last output value, but rather the value were the function stops returning values.
range(1,3) will give you 1,2, so your function has to be range(1st value, last value+1)
http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range